# Check ProjectReferences in a .csproj files with roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, roslyn, csproj, analyzer

I want to write custom rules with roslyn to check if the references in my .csproj files are correct.

But i'm new to this and can't find any good documentation or examples how to do this.

Can someone give me a hint or an example how i start or do this?

**--------------------------EDIT--------------------------**

I tried it with this

```
 public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterCompilationAction(AnalyzeCompilation);
    }

    private void AnalyzeCompilation(CompilationAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var compilation = context.Compilation;
        int referenceCount = compilation.References.Count();
        if (referenceCount > 1)
        {
            context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, null, compilation.AssemblyName, referenceCount));              
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Try with the `Compilation` class - the `References` property should contain all you need. You could obtain the `Compilation` class through the context of `RegisterCompilationAction` or any other `Register*Action`.

Comment: Firstly, do you want to add this rules as visual studio extensions or you just want to do that for analyzing .proj file? Secondly, do you want to know, that `Reference` is `ProjectReference`, `PackageReference`, `Reference` or something else?

Comment: @Valeri-SonarSource thanks, i try it with that.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria i want to add this rule as visual studio extension or add it to an analyzer, maybe write my own analyzer. I need the Reference and the ProjectReference.

Comment: @Valeri-SonarSource i tried it with the compilation class but i think it did something wrong

Comment: I don't think a Roslyn analyzer is going to help you analyze a project file.  It is meant to analyze the source code.  You can check which metadata references are being used by a Compilation, but there is no guarantee that you'll be able to map this back to specific project.